# Break video into images for processing

Tags: haskell, image-processing, video-processing

I have recently found [friday](https://github.com/RaphaelJ/friday), a image processing library for haskell and it seems pretty nice so far, but I would like to be able to load videos and break them up into images. Is there such a library available for haskell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice there are some slick [ffmpeg bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ffmpeg-light) that stream images from a video in the JuicyPixel image types.  There is already a [ticket](https://github.com/RaphaelJ/friday/issues/12) for making `friday` and `JuicyPixels` play nice - if you are actually interested in getting this done in a clean manner I highly recommend you make a patch to friday addressing this ticket.

Also, since the friday maintainer is busy till September, I'd be happy to merge an of your changes with mine on [my own repository](https://github.com/TomMD/friday) for general use.

EDIT: This is fun.  A way to get a lazy list of images is with `unsafeInterleaveIO`:

```
module LazyDemo where

import Vision.Image.JuicyPixels
import Vision.Image (RGBA)
import Codec.FFmpeg
import System.IO.Unsafe

lazyStream :: FilePath -> IO [RGBA]
lazyStream fp = do
    initFFmpeg
    (rd,close) <- imageReader fp
    go rd close
  where
   go rd close = do
       mi <- rd
       case mi of
           Nothing -> close >> return []
           Just i  -> (toFridayRGBA i : ) <$> unsafeInterleaveIO (go rd close)
```

Comment: Nice thnx. I will take a look

Comment: @fakedrake I made a juicypixels to friday conversion library (https://github.com/TomMD/friday-juicypixels) and it works beautifully with ffmpeg-light.  Thanks for the motivation.

Comment: Wow you are awesome! So how would you make a lazy list of friday images from a video with ffmpeg in haskell?

Comment: @fakedrake see my edit, it's just an application of unsafeInterleaveIO

Comment: This was probably the answer on stackoverflow that taught me the most so far. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I do not know whether such a library exists, but I suspect not. Video codecs are pretty complicated. If something for haskell exists, it would most likely be an `ffmpeg` wrapper. Anyway, I would use the `ffmpeg` command line tool directly if you only need to extract the frames from some videos. Or use a system call to do it dynamically.

The ffmpeg command is pretty simple for this task:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -an -f image2 "output_%05d.jpg"
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence